# Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 and 2008 on the same machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a Windows Server 2008 using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and I want to try VS2010 Beta 2 but I'm not confident it will not tarnish my original development setup.

Has anyone tried to install VS2010 B2 on the same machine as a VS2008?

I've also tried to install VS2010 B2 on a virtual machine (using VMWare 6.5 and Windows XP) but the thing was horribly slow and it crashed all the time. Has anyone had a successful experience when installing it on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have both running on a VM with no issues. I have coworkers running both on a primary machine. It should work just fine, you just need to make sure that when you run `vsvars` from the command line, you get the `vsvars` that you want.

Comment: I'm running both VS 2008 and Beta2 of VS2010 on my primary dev machine, no issues.

Answer (score 3):

I have had no problems installing Visual Studio in a Virtual Machine, however the speed was not even half of that if it was running natively - I am guessing due to graphics drivers and WPF being used a lot in Visual Studio 2010 as when I upgraded to VMware Workstation 7, it has got a lot better (but still not as good as native).

Lastly, to what you asked in the subject, I have had no problems - Visual Studio is VERY good at having multiple versions installed on the same computer - you can pretty much install every version that has ever existed and not have any problems...

... That being said, as much as I have not had any problems, I would warn you about installing Beta code on any production machine as you will have to thoroughly uninstall it all before upgrading to a release version.